# Does $A \subset B \implies B \notin A $?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm also interested in the converse of this: does $A \in B \implies B \not\subset A $?

I can give examples where the first one holds: (e.g. $ A = \{1,2,3\}, B= \{1,2,3,4\}$), or the second one holds ($A=\{1\}, B=\{\{1\}\} $), but I can't come up with counterexamples for either of them.

Comment: Can you resolve whether it's possible that $B\in B$? (i.e. what sort of axioms for set theory are you familiar with? This is fairly easy in ZFC, but maybe less clear if you're used to working informally)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have a set contain itself ([see this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1046863/how-can-a-set-contain-itself)). Assume $B \in A$. Then $A = \{B,...\} \subset B$ is a contradiction. To answer your other question, $A \in B \implies B = \{A,...\} \not\subset A$.

Answer (score 2):

- Suppose A is included in B .
- It means that : all the elements of A are also elements of B.
- Now, in case B is a member of A, then, by the rule stated above, B is a member of B ( for the rule holds for all the elements of A, and B is supposed to be one of these).
- So, you question amounts to : does the relation " being a member of" possibly hold between an object and itself, or , is rather this relation absolutely irreflexive?

Answer (score 0):

You should understand the difference between the two symbols **⊂** and **∈** .
**[1] A ⊂ B⟹B ∉ A**

1. When you say **A ⊂ B**, this implies that set A is a subset of set B; which implies that all the elements of set A, are also elements of set B.
   For example, let set A = {1, 2} and set B = {1, 2, 3}. Here all the elements of set A are also in set B, so A⊂B.
2. When you say **B ∈ A**, this implies that set B is an element of set A.
   For example, let set B = {1, 2, 3} then set A would contain set B, along with the possibility of other elements, then A = {**{1, 2, 3}**, …}.
   So, if **A⊂B**, it cannot contain set B as a member, hence in this case **B∈A** is not possible.

**[2] A ∈ B ⟹ B ⊄ A**
When A ∈ B this implies B = {A, …}. In this case, it holds good that B⊄A.